# Database Transaction Partially Committing

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a segment of code in PHP / MySQL that looks kind of like:

```
foreach item
    try
        BEGIN
        update table 1, throw if failed
        update table 2, throw if failed
        update table 3, throw if failed
        etc. etc. etc.
        COMMIT
        print "COMMITTING"
    catch
        ROLLBACK
        print "ROLLING BACK"
    end try
end foreach
```

I've been getting issues where I receive the "COMMITTING" message consistently from every single iteration but on occasion (seems to be random), none of the updates will commit apart from the last one, which always commits.

All tables are InnoDB. Anyone know what the issue might be?

Edit: Here's a simplified version of the code, hopefully it'll be sufficient to root out the issue?

```
foreach($auctions as $a) {  

    try {

        mysql_query("BEGIN");   
        $items = fetchAll("SELECT * FROM users_auctions_items WHERE amount > 0 AND auction = {$a['id']}");
        $highBid = fetchOne("SELECT * FROM users_auctions_bids WHERE auction = {$a['id']} AND status = 0 LIMIT 1");

        if($highBid === false) {

            echo "No high bid, returning items to {$a['user']}\n";
            $recipientId = $a['user'];

        } else {

            $recipientId = $highBid['user'];
            echo "High bid by {$recipientId}\n";
            echo "Giving {$highBid['amount']} gold to {$a['user']}...\n";   
            mysql_query("UPDATE users SET gold = gold + {$highBid['amount']} WHERE id = {$a['user']}");
            if(mysql_affected_rows() != 1) throw new Exception();

        }

        if($items) {
            foreach($items as $i) {
                echo "Giving {$recipientId} item #{$i['item']} (x{$i['amount']})...\n";
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO users_inventory (user, item, amount) 
                    VALUES ({$recipientId}, {$i['item']}, {$i['amount']}) 
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount = amount + {$i['amount']}");
                if(mysql_affected_rows() < 1) throw new Exception();
            }
        }

        mysql_query("UPDATE users_auctions SET status = 2 WHERE id = {$a['id']}");
        if(mysql_affected_rows() != 1) throw new Exception();

        mysql_query("COMMIT");
        echo "Committing\n";

    } catch(Exception $e) {

        echo "Rolling back\n";              
        mysql_query("ROLLBACK");

    }

}
```

To be more specific: This is run by a cron every few minutes, and is supposed to run through all the outstanding auctions and distribute the goods - afterwards, it sets the auction to complete. Although the logs say that it's running perfectly and it finds the correct goods and users, it occasionally updates the auction to complete without distributing the assets.

If I reset the auction back to being incomplete and let the cron run again, it usually completes with no issues (sometimes I have to reset it 2-3 times).

Comment: I see nothing wrong in this psudocode. Perhaps the real code has a bug you didn't notice.

Comment: Please give us the real code. You may have something there.

Comment: @Ariel I've updated the post with more details, thank you for your assistance :)

Comment: @Truth I've updated the post with more details, thank you for your assistance :)

Comment: @fluke: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Sorry, I see nothing wrong in the real code either. Sorry I can't help you. Maybe enable MySQL query logging (logs every single query), and see if any spurious rollbacks show up.